# vscode typecheck javascript file against its own definition file

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

With type-checking enabled in javascript project, vscode supports development perfectly.
But I feel my code looks kind of overloaded use jsdoc for further type definitions. So I work with `*.d.ts` files.

When referring from another file vscode really show all its gadgets and stuff. But within the javascript file itself the suggestions does not show up.

So e.g. editing util.js does not show types of util.d.ts

Any idea how to configure or resolve such?

Some Example Code:

```
// example.js
function buildXTest(name, value) {
   return {name, value};
}
exports.buildXTest = buildXTest;

// example.d.ts
type Property = {
   name:string;
   value:any;
}
export function buildXTest(name:string, value:any):Property;

// example_use.js
const {buildXTest} = require('./example')
buildXTest()

// vscode tooltip in example.js shows
// buildXTest(name: any, value: any): { name: any; value: any; }
    
// vscode tooltip in example_use.js
// buildXTest(name: string, value: any): Property
```

Comment: Why not just use TypeScript at this point?

Comment: Can you update the question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (incl. JS, DTS, TSConfig, etc.)?

Comment: For sure I can use typescript, but I just want to try out - this could be very helpful when modifying or debugging old style javascript projects

Comment: added some code examples